# How to return a string from LibraryLink?

Tags: librarylink

I need to return a string from a LibraryLink function.  The documentation [states](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html):

> When a string is returned as a result, the Wolfram Language accesses the memory to convert it to its own internal string format, but does not attempt to free the memory. Thus, if your program allocates a string for a result, it also needs to free that memory, but in a separate function from the one setting the string result, since the Wolfram Language needs to access the string memory after the library function has returned.

Does this really mean that I need to have *two* functions to be able to return the string, one to return it and one to free the memory?  Is there really no simpler way?

Based on my interpretation the *minimal* work needed to return a dynamically allocated string is what's shown at the end of the post.  Is this correct?  This looks quite tedious.

Is there a way to let Mathematica manage the memory for the string (including allocation and freeing, as with MTensors)?

(To be fair: it can be expected that in many cases one would want to return a pre-defined string in which case there is no need to free it.  Sometimes the string is dynamically allocated though, and it becomes necessary to free it.)

---

In this example use C++'s `std::string` to save some work, but using simple `char *` in C would be analogous, with some added tedium.

```cpp
std::string *str = NULL; // ugly global variable

extern "C" DLLEXPORT int get_string(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    str = new std::string("some string to return");
    MArgument_setUTF8String(Res, const_cast<char *>(str->c_str()));
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR
}

extern "C" DLLEXPORT int free_string(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    delete str;
    str = NULL;
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR
}
```

Then in Mathematica:

```
iGetString = LibraryFunctionLoad["lib", "get_string", {}, "UTF8String"]
iFreeString = LibraryFunctionLoad["lib", "free_string", {}, "Void"]

getString[] := 
  PreemptProtect@AbortProtect@Module[{str},
    str = iGetString[];
    iFreeString[];
    str
  ]
```

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78894/4330) is a complete example of the technique showed by Szabolcs (the OP) using C instead of C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, but it's not necessary to expose the free_string method. Just delete the string you allocated in subsequent calls to get_string. Something like this …

```
if (str!=NULL) {
  delete str;
}    
str = new std::string("some string to return");
```